Explaining "defined over"

Definition: Let $\Omega$ be an algebraically closed field and $k\subset \Omega$ a subfield. $G<GL(\Omega)$ is a linear algebraic group. $G$ is defined over $k$ if the ideal $I$ of polynomials vanishing on $G$ is generated by the intersection of $I$ with the algebra of polynomials with coefficients in $k$.

This definition is from the paper:https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.06897. (p9)
I do not quite understand what this means(generated by the intersection of the algebra with coefficient in $k$?). Can anyone provide a concrete example to illustrate it? I am still a sophomore now, please forgive me if this question is simple. Thanks for any help.

The group structure isn't really relevant here, so let's look at the analogous question for algebraic subvarieties of the affine plane $\Omega^d$. For example, let's take $d = 1$, $\Omega = \mathbf{C}$ and $k = \mathbf{Q}$.
If $V$ is the set $\{0, 1\} \subset \mathbf{C}$, then the ideal $I \subset \mathbf{C}[X]$ is the ideal generated by $X(X-1)$. Since $X(X-1) \in \mathbf{Q}[X]$, it follows that $I \cap \mathbf{Q}[X]$ contains a set of generators of $I$ as an ideal of $\mathbf{C}[X]$.
If $V$ is the set $\{i, -i\}$ we have the same picture: $I$ is generated by $(X - i)(X + i) = X^2 + 1$, which lies in $I \cap \mathbf{Q}[X]$. So $V$ is "defined over $\mathbf{Q}$" in this sense (showing that "being defined over $\mathbf{Q}$" doesn't imply that all points of $V$ have coordinates in $\mathbf{Q}$).
On the other hand, if $V$ is the set $\{i\}$, then $I$ is generated by $X - i$ which is obviously not in $\mathbf{Q}[X]$, and with a little effort one can show that $I \cap \mathbf{Q}[X]$ is the ideal $(X^2 + 1) \mathbf{Q}[X]$. So $I \cap \mathbf{Q}[X]$ does not contain a generating set for $I$ as an ideal of $\mathbf{C}[X]$, thus $V$ is not defined over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Thank you for your answer!!
